# argo workflow API to change image tag in template

Tags: kubernetes, argo-workflows, argocd

we are using argoworkflow + argo-sensors to trigger our test-automation via REST endpoints.

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Sensor
metadata:
  name: fe-tests-sensor
  labels:
    sensors.argoproj.io/sensor-controller-instanceid: argo-events
    argo-events-sensor-version: v0.11
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        nodeNamespace: default
      containers:
        - name: "sensor"
          image: "argoproj/sensor:v0.11"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: argo-events-sa
  dependencies:
    - name: "webhook-gateway:fe-tests"
  ....
  triggers:
    - template:
        name: webhook-autotest-trigger
        group: argoproj.io
        version: v1alpha1
        resource: workflows
        source:
          inline: |
            apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
            kind: Workflow
            metadata:
              generateName: fe-test-
            spec:
              entrypoint: fe-tests
              templates:
                - name: fe-tests
                  nodeSelector:
                    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: spot-m4large
                  container:
                    image: <our-ecr-link>/fe-automation:latest
                  ....
```

Is there any API or best practice how to change image tag without modifying manifest and making `kubectl apply ...` manually?

Comment: Is there information in the event itself that could be used to infer the correct tag?

Comment: @MichaelCrenshaw not at the moment, but we can add REST param to pass the tag info. But then I don't know how to substitute image string from event param section. ( if thats possible of course )